# Use 2 different 404 pages dependent on directory

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to use 2 separate 404 pages depending on what directory the user is currently in. I thought you could do this with an .htaccess file in the directory however it's not working. Is this even possible?

Example: user is looking at a document in  www.domain.com. This directory should use number1_404.html.

Example2: user is looking at a document in www.domain.com/other_directory. This directory should use number2_404.html.

I am not sure totally how to write a rule for this but this is what I have now and it's not working.

```
.htaccess <--- in the root folder /httpdocs
ErrorDocument 404 /root_404.php

.htaccess <---- in the subdirectory /httpdocs/subdirectory
ErrorDocument 404 /subdirectory/subdirectory_404.php
```

perhaps I'm not understanding how this all works so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: THat's how ErrorDocument works, you're doing it right, something else must be wrong

Comment: yes, I realized that I had extra white space at the bottom of the .htaccess file and it was making apache unhappy. Once I removed the white space it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 different .htaccess files. One in the root for the root 404 and one in the sub directory also look into rewrite conditions, there may be a condition you can apply its similar to if-else in other languages. Maybe you can do something like the equivlent of if root show this, else show that. I don't know for sure though as I haven't had a need to use more than one 404.

An alternative may be also, seeing as your using PHP is to detect via php if you are in the root directory or if you are one or more levels up. Where if that be the case you `include()` or `require()` whatever your choice is, the 404 you want displayed for the condition. Globally however it would be one 404 page for the htaccess file, that would pull in one of two others (or more if you ever have the need).

Comment: if i use different `htaccess` file for sub folder then do i have to paste all other `.htaccess` rules? or just if i add `ErrorDocument 404` in new `htaccess` and ignore all other rules. do other rules from root folder work on sub folder apart from 404?